# Why is runtimeConfig doesn't see environment variables in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

1. I do `yarn build` without the `.env` file
2. Add the `.env` file to the project
3. I do `yarn start`.
4. Print the `useRuntimeConfig().public.baseURL` to the console and get `undefined`.

Why is runtime not tracking my environment variables?

**.env**

```
NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://example.com/api/v1
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseUrl: ''
    }
  },
```

**plugins/app.js**

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  console.log('baseURL', useRuntimeConfig().public.baseURL
})
```

Comment: :)
````JavaScript
baseUrl !== baseURL 

````
strings dont match

Answer (score 2):

Even though your setup is following the documentation to the t, I also experience this not working in production. I am using a Linux server and I am deploying using pm2.
Bart has already answered with this option:

```
baseUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
```

This is the solution that ended up working for me. Though it's not like you have set it up wrong. According to the documentation setting baseUrl to an empty string should be correct and should be overwritten by the value from the .env file. It even explicitly tells you not to set it up this way because it says this will break at runtime. The prescribed method doesn't work though, it works in development, not in production in my case.

It seems Nuxt doesn't want to take responsibility explaining how to properly set this up for production because there is tor many variables to take into account as every server environment is different. But I feel they could have at least mentioned that this might not work in production to save developers (like me) stressful moments going live with a project...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation page](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/runtime-config#environment-variables):

> However, after your server is built, you are responsible for setting environment variables when you run the server. Your .env file will not be read at this point. How you do this is different for every environment. On a Linux server, you could pass the environment variables as arguments using the terminal DATABASE_HOST=mydatabaseconnectionstring node .output/server/index.mjs. Or you could source your env file using source .env && node .output/server/index.mjs.
> Note that for a purely static site, it is not possible to set runtime configuration config after your project is prerendered.

So, `source .env && yarn start` should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to do the same, but unfortunely it doesn't work for me

Comment: Actually `DATABASE_HOST=mydatabaseconnectionstring node .output/server/index.mjs` works, but `source .env && node .output/server/index.mjs` does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You might check the version of nuxt.

If it's the bridge version, `runtimeConfig` cannot work.

Cause I use @nuxt/bridge, not work.

and then it worked on the `3.0.0-rc.3` version. I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
baseUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
```

try it that way. what you do is setting it explicitly to a empty string.

Answer (score 0):

the function useRuntimeConfig() is a problem why are you probably using it within a plugin or a ultility file, odando error in time of excution.
use it only on components and pages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using this in component.

but that shit is still not working.



```
const config = useRuntimeConfig().public;

// alert(config.public.apiEndpoint);
// console.log('apiLink - ' + config.apiLink);
console.log('apiEndpoint -  ' + config.apiEndpoint);
console.log('apiBase - ' + config.apiBase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to explicitely set `baseUrl` to `NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL`

You just have to define your variables inside your `.env` into your environment variables:

`export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && node .output/server/index.mjs`

related documentation:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#example

related issue :
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/26520